# having a script autorun on a web server

Tags: scripting, automation

sorry if my question is a bit ambiguous, I'll explain what i want to do.

i want to run a game on a webserver. its a turn based game, some of you people might have come across it. 
Its a game called mafia: http://mafiascum.net/wiki/index.php?title=Newbie_Guide.

I know how it needs to work in terms of a mysql database a server side scripting language etc etc.

What i am not sure about is whats the best way to get a script to activate when the game starts, and be able to run a script every 3 minutes to update the game status:

once 10 people join the game starts

people vote during a 3 minute period. (votes would be stored in a database)

after 3 minutes a script needs to run to calculate the votes and remove a player

then 1 and a half minutes later the script needs to run again.

This cycle of 3 minutes, 1 and a half minutes need to repeat until a certain condition is met, i.e  all players but 2 are dead or something.

when players refresh the page they need to be updated on the games status.

Ive read about sockets, and wonder if this might be a good path to take. would sockets be able to send json back to the clients? so that jquery can then update the client with game results.

Ideally i would like the the front end to be done in jquery and the backend script processing to be done by php or something.

How open would this be? in terms of people trying to cheat by sending attacks such as post variables sqli attacks etc etc.

Its quite a broad question, and i am sure there is more than one approcah so is more than one correct answer, but i would be intrested on peoples thoughts on how they would go about developing it.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a CRON job or similar on the backend to update the status every x seconds as you have suggested.

To trigger a game start, simply fire off a PHP command to set your CRON job running.

This way the timing is controlled behind the scenes on the server, and you are free to update the status of the game using jQuery to your actual players.

Comment: thanks luke, how would i go about setting a cron job run in php? i might have about 10 or 15 games running at the same time, would this slow down the server a great deal, all the script would do is update records in the database, so ots actual functions would not create too much overhead i dont think

Comment: I found some useful information here: http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-php-cron-jobs-regular-scheduled-tasks-in-php-172/.  Regarding the speed, its difficult to answer as I have no way of knowing how labour intensive your data is going to be.   That said, you should definitely script some performance testing - to answer questions such as "how will this game run with 1,000" players simultaneously?